# Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'data.json' when running `jsonplaceholder`

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run `jsonplaceholder` I get:

```
jsonplaceholder
JSONPlaceholder listening on http://localhost:3000

fs.js:432
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'data.json'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:286:15)
    at Object.index.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jsonplaceholder/node_modules/json-server/node_modules/lowdb/node_modules/underscore.db/src/node.js:11:24)
    at Function.low.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jsonplaceholder/node_modules/json-server/node_modules/lowdb/lib/index.js:110:29)
    at reset (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jsonplaceholder/index.js:6:14)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jsonplaceholder/index.js:14:3)
    at Server.g (events.js:180:16)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at net.js:1052:10
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Im on Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 2):

Project's author here. Just to let you know, finally, this (old) bug was fixed. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: if you have a solution - please add it as an answer (rather than just telling us it was fixed). That way, if anybody else comes across the same error - they can use your solution to help them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure if this has anything to do with an outdated module, or a messed up npm installation or maybe I'm just lucky, but basically the problem is that the path to access "data.json" is wrong (maybe not wrong but incomplete).

What I did was open file:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jsonplaceholder/index.js
```

and modify the following function:

```
function reset() {
//  server.low.load('data.json') <-- ORIGINAL LINE
server.low.load(require('path').resolve(__dirname, 'data.json')); //<--MY FIX
}
```

Just save the file, and run jsonplaceholder again.